# Java: can I get different class instances for the same variable?

Tags: java

Assume three classes: Class1, Class2 and Class3 plus a single variable value.

What I'd like to do is this:

```
??? value;
switch (someInt) {
   case 1: value = new Class1(); break;
   case 2: value = new Class2(); break;
   case 3: value = new Class3(); break;
}
```

I'm looking to use this construct in JavaFX for various classes which are similar for many getters and setters, but also differ in a few (hence the different class names which are all derived from the same parent class).

Is there some way of implementing the above?

I have evaluated some of the answers, but I still cannot quite see an answer to my problem, so here is a concrete example:

Here are three classes I'm trying to assign to shadow (I know I cannot do it        like this, it's just for illustration):

```
Shadow shadow;
DropShadow shadow;
InnerShadow shadow;

switch (sType) {
    case "SHADOW" : shadow = new Shadow(); break;
    case "DROPSHADOW" : shadow = new DropShadow(); break;
    case "INNERSHADOW" : shadow = new InnerShadow(); break;
}

// All these classes share the same parameters

shadow.setColor(Color.BLACK);
....
shadow.setRadius(2.0); 

fieldContent.setEffect(shadow); 
// This will then set any one of the three shadows
```

Comment: To not throw OOP concepts in the wastebasket, the 3 classes should share some type, if only the same interface, and then make value a variable of this type. If you make value type `Object` you're asking for trouble.

Comment: Yes, you can use `Object value;` or any type which is the super type of all three classes.

Comment: These are obviously conflicting answers. Can any of you explain your answer a little further?

Comment: The devil is in the details, meaning any *specific* answer will depend on the specifics of your problem. Please tell us more about the *concrete* details of your problem, so we can give a much more specific and helpful answer. Note that if value is of type `Object` this means some ugly instanceof and casting later in your code. Again, don't go this route.

Comment: Not really contradicting, you can doesn't mean you should do it like that. I agree with the first comment. Here some keywords to look into: `abstract`, `extends`, `interface`, `implements`...

Comment: Read about Polymorphism here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_%28computer_science%29

Comment: OK, it sounds like you want to implement the Command or Strategy Design Pattern. So yes, use interfaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certainly. All classes in Java by default have `Object` as their root so you could have

```
Object value;

//...
switch (someInt) {
    case 1: value = new Class1(); break;
    case 2: value = new Class2(); break;
    case 3: value = new Class3(); break;
}
```

Or if all the classes implement or extend some other functionality:

```
public interface AwesomeClass {
    public void method();
}

public class Class1 implements AwesomeClass {
    public void method() {
        // do class1 thing
    }
}

public class Class2 implements AwesomeClass {
    public void method() {
        // do class2 thing
    }
}

// ...

AwesomeClass value;
switch (someInt) {
    case 1: value = new Class1(); break;
    case 2: value = new Class2(); break;
}
```

Here's another example if the classes extend a base class

```
public class Animal {
    public void eat() { }

    public void walk() { }
}

public class Cat extends Animal {
    public void eat() {
        // eat like a cat
    }

    public void walk() {
        // walk like a cat (on four legs)
    }

public class Horse extends Animal {
    public void eat() {
        // eat like a horse
    }

    public void walk() {
        // walk like a horse
    }
}

Animal myAnimal;
switch(typeOfAnimal) {
    case 1: myAnimal = new Cat(); break;
    case 2: myAnimal = new Horse(); break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `Class1`, `Class2` and `Class3` implement a common interface, or extend a common base-class you can use that. As posted, you could use the common ancestor of all Java instances (`Object`). You also need `break` statements because `case`(s) fall-through. Like,

```
Object value;
switch (someInt) {
case 1:
    value = new Class1(); 
    break; 
case 2: 
    value = new Class2(); 
    break;
case 3: 
    value = new Class3(); 
    break;
}
```